# Climbing before 1950: photography book/database

Tags: rock-climbing, resources, alps, history, books

I am looking for a book or digital database of rock climbing pictures from before 1950.

I tried to search online, but, except for a few pictures, I didn't have much luck. Also, the name of the photographer and/or the source are often not reported in the pictures that I found online.

The period I am more interested in is the 1920s-40s, the "golden age" of rock climbing in Europe. To be even more specific, I would be very happy to find some photography book/database about climbing in the Alps in the 1920s-40s.

Answer (score 5):

I found a site that has a number of old climbing photographs from around that time and I think is your best option (that I could find).

[Historical Rock Climbing Images 1890s - 1930s](http://www128.pair.com/r3d4k7/HistoricalClimbingImages1.html)

There is also the [Yorkshire Ramblers Journal](http://www.yrc.org.uk/yrcweb/index.php/journal) which goes back all the way to 1899 and some of the articles have pictures.

From that one call pull the names of the photographers and use that to run more Google searches to find more images.

- [Oliver Perry-Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Perry-Smith), there is also a [profile of him with photos.](http://www.northconwayrockclimbs.com/support-material/Oliver.Perry.Smith.Profile.of.a.Mountaineer.pdf)
- [Guy d. Barton](https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&as_q=%22guy%20d.%20barton%22%20photography&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&imgsz=&imgar=&imgc=&imgcolor=&imgtype=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=)
- [G. A. Fowkes](https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&as_q=%22G.%20A.%20Fowkes%22&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&imgsz=&imgar=&imgc=&imgcolor=&imgtype=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=)
- [Claude Barton](http://www.yrc.org.uk/yrcweb/index.php/journal/vols1-5/44-vol1-cat/no3/78-v1n3p213)
- [Walter Hahn](https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&as_q=%22Walter%20Hahn%22%20climbing&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&imgsz=&imgar=&imgc=&imgcolor=&imgtype=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=)
- [R. Kobach](https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&as_q=%22R.%20Kobach%22%20climbing&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&imgsz=&imgar=&imgc=&imgcolor=&imgtype=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=)

You can also find a few by looking for some of the climbers of that era

- [Emilio Comici](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Emilio_Comici)
- [Toni Kurz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toni_Kurz)
- [Andreas Hinterstoisser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Hinterstoisser)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. To the list of climbers of that era, I can add a few if other people happen to look for the same thing: Emil Solleder, Riccardo Cassin, Angelo Dibona, the Dimai brothers.